# Is it possible to export FBX or OBJ files from Aveva marine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, type-conversion, fbx, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I want to export 3D models made in Aveva Marine to be used in the Unity game engine.
Is it possible to export models to **.FBX** or **.OBJ** directly from Aveva Marine or I need to do use conversion software?

I haven't found any other way that can do that without converting to another format first.

Comment: You could using [Pixyz](https://unity.com/products/pixyz) for sure... otherwise it depends on what export options Aveva provides...

Answer (score 0):

The file formats of your model exports depends on your Aveva Marine software version. I believe **.FBX** and **.OBJ** are both supported formats using the **Export** function in the software. If this doesn't seem to work you are going to need to export it in a not very specific type like **.RVM** and use a conversion tool to turn it into an **.FBX**

Comment: Do you know which versions have option to export as fbx?